# How does the WITH statement store the record set for the select query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, with-statement

Consider the following SQL (SQL Server 2008) statement:

```
WITH MyResult AS
(
  SELECT 
    Name,
    Row_ID AS ORD
  FROM Person Where Gender = @Gender
)
SELECT *
FROM MyResult
WHERE ORD > 5
```

Is MyResult stored in a temporary table in the tempdb? Or does it do something else?

We are optimising some queries and would lke to better understand WITH statements (internally) to help gauge performance etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx)

> ...the CTE is a language-level
>   construct—meaning that SQL Server does
>   not internally create temp or virtual
>   tables...

And also, [as mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

> A common table expression (CTE) can be
>   thought of as a temporary result set
>   that is defined within the execution
>   scope of a single SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW
>   statement. A CTE is similar to a
>   derived table in that it is not stored
>   as an object and lasts only for the
>   duration of the query.

Comment: "...a temporary result set..." triggered our thinking that a temporary result set is being stored somewhere temporarily (ie. tempdb)

Comment: @Russell - Yeah I can see where the wording is a bit cloudy on this. Using a CTE in itself, SQL Server does not create a temp table. Of course, just like any query, CTE or no CTE, it could be paged out to tempdb depending on what's going on. But that's not specific to CTEs